# Parsing X12 File to Json File

Tags: java, json, parsing, x12

I wanted to parse x12 format file to json file using java.
I didn't find any information regarding this on internet.
can someone please tell me how to do this or any jar file which can be able to do this is also fine.

Comment: It's just text.  Download an EDI editor, learn the formatting of X12 and then parse it into your JSON.  Or, get a commercial translator that would allow you drag/drop mapping paradigms and also handle some of the X12 workflow (997s, TP management, reports, etc)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Andrew, can you please tell me the names of  commercial translators which can do this.

Answer (score 1):

How to do it:

1. Obtain documentation on your x12 file (do you mean HIPAA data exchange?). It will tell you about the different records, their layout and sequencing
2. Define target schema for the JSON you want to produce. Surely you don't want to produce just *any* JSON
3. Define mapping. Draw spaghetti on a whiteboard, piece of paper, or something like Altova Mapforce, until you have all elements connected.
4. Choose your transformation approach depending on the dataset size - [streaming](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi) or [object to JSON serialization](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind)
5. Implement
6. Look for performance bottlenecks. Introduce optimizations to speed up processing.